# Strange method output

Tags: go, methods

I am confused about the output from my simple program. I expect to get all four names in the output, but I cannot get the first name in the output. Please help me clear this, or some resource about that.

```
type Employees struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    chandran := Employees{Name: "Chandran"}
    darpan := Employees{Name: "Darpan"}
    ishaan := Employees{Name: "Ishaan"}
    manbir := Employees{Name: "Manbir"}

    Employees.structName(chandran, darpan, ishaan, manbir)
}

func (e Employees) structName(names ...Employees){
    fmt.Println(names)
}
```

[**Code in go Playground**](https://go.dev/play/p/x6SPq4CrmMW)

Comment: A small note: The language is called simply "Go", not "golang". Certainly not "golang language" since that's entirely redundant.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I already edited that part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no "static" methods in Go. To call a method, you must have a value of the receiver type, and call the method on that value.

So you must call it like this:

```
var e Employees
e.structName(chandran, darpan, ishaan, manbir)
```

Or simply:

```
Employees{}.structName(chandran, darpan, ishaan, manbir)
```

Both these output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/nYy5WZGNhT0)):

```
[{Chandran} {Darpan} {Ishaan} {Manbir}]
```

#### Why does your version omit the first argument?

Because what you have is in fact a [method expression](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_expressions), and you are calling that method expression.

Let's look at it in details:

```
Employees.structName
```

is a method expression, and it is a callable function. Its signature is the signature of the `structName` method, the parameter list prefixed with the receiver. So the type of `Employees.structName` is:

```
func(main.Employees, ...main.Employees)
```

You call this by passing 4 employees, first of which will be the receiver, and only the remaining 3 will be used as the `names` argument. So only the names starting from the second will be printed.

Answer (score 3):

According to the language specification:

https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_expressions

The expression

```
Employees.structName(chandran, darpan, ishaan, manbir)
```

is equivalent to:

```
chandran.strucName(darpan,ishaan,manbir)
```

This is because the first argument to the function `Employees.structName` is interpreted as the receiver to the method.

If you do:

```
Employees{}.structName(chandran, darpan, ishaan, manbir)
```

it will print all four elements.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should name your Strut Employee instead of Employees. since it represents only one employee. If you want to have methods on a group(slice) of employees.

```
type Employee struct {
    Name string
}

type Employees struct {
    employees []Employee
}
```

then define function on that group type Employees:

```
func (e *Employees) Add(names ...Employee) {
    e.employees = append(e.employees, names...)
}

func (e Employees) structName() {
    fmt.Println(e.employees)
}
```

I made a [Demo](https://go.dev/play/p/Huvp3U9XofA) on Go Playground with an Add and StructName function.